# OpenFileDialog.FileName always has suffix '[1]' if open from FTP location

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ftp, openfiledialog

This is a bit strange.  I'm doing `FTP` file downloading, and use `OpenFileDialog` to select file.  But the fileName always has suffix `[1]`.

For example, my filename in FTP folder is `Foo.txt`, the `OpenFileDialog.FileName` are like those:

> C:\Users\xfh378\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet
>   Files\Content.IE5\8FKRB2DC\Foo[1].txt
>
> C:\Users\xfh378\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet
>   Files\Content.IE5\PQ0F2DSB\Foo[1].txt

My code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult re = this.openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    if (re == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(this.openFileDialog1.FileName);
    }
}
```

I am using .NET 4.0, VS2010, Win7.

Comment: This is not strange...this is the expected behavior of Internet Explorer to avoid having multiple files of the same name in the same folder. Try to use IE to download the same file (or different file with the same name) to the same folder multiple times. You'll get this as well.

Comment: @kayson: I'm just browsing and selecting the filename, I haven't downloaded even a single time. By the way, I did not find [0], [2], [3]... and so on no matter how many times of browsing. Can you find?

Comment: The path you're referring to is a temp download path used by Windows. They have *already* be downloaded.

Comment: @kayson: then is there anyway to get the exactly right selected filename?